# Case insensitive in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a search function that I am creating,  in which I am trying to achieve in performing a search through several objects to perform a search on an object's name property to return a result. I am also trying to make the code case insensitive, so if a user were to type in 'CaT' or 'cat' in a search field, they would still return the "Cat" object. I am a new user to JS, and am familiar with toLowerCase/toUpperCase but reg/exp I struggle with. If anyone can supply any hints as to what I am doing wrong with this code?

```
function search(animals, name) {
    if (animals.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
        return animals; 
}
```

}

// new edit
Prompt question and my original code was as followed:

Implement a function called `search` with a signature of `search(animals, name) { //... }` that:
   - Takes a paramater representing an Array of `animals`.
   - Takes a paramater representing a String, the name of an animal on which to perform a search.
   - Looks through the `animals` Array, and returns the animal's Object if an animal with that name exists.
   - Returns `null` if no animal with that name exists

```
function search(animals, name) {

    for (var i = 0; i < animals.length-1; i++) {
        if (animals[i].name === name) {
            return animals[i];
        } else {
            console.log(null) 
        }
    }
}
```

this worked in matching to the property of the object if it was typed in the EXACT casing it was created. All I'm trying to do is make the function work with whatever casing.

Comment: `animals.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase("name")` - that you are using the same method here in two completely different ways does not make you stop and go, huh? Especially since you are doing the same thing differently on the next line then, for the apparently totally superfluous `equal` variable ...

Comment: what is the function supposed to do? searching or compairing? please name accordingly.

Comment: The function is suppose to search through an array of objects and return the correct object once the function identifies the typed in string matches the value on the property of the object.

Comment: Is `animals` an array? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: please add some more data, like the one you are taking for comparison.

Comment: animals is an array, and name is the argument that is pass through to compare to the object's property.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] with the emphasis on *complete*

Comment: I am updating my question with as much detail as I can provide. Keep in mind, I am new to programing and to Stack Overflow, and learning and trying to understand all these concepts. So I apologize in advance if  my question comes across as undetailed/choppy language or it seems like I don't know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var animals = ["cat", "dog", "cow"];

function search(animal, name) {
  
  if (animal.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log("Matchs with : " + animal);
  } else {
    console.log("Not match with : " + animal);
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  console.clear();
  var nameInput = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  animals.forEach(function(entry) {
    search(entry, nameInput);
  });

}
```

```html
Animal Name: <input type="text" id="myText" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

Comment: where do you use this `var name = "CaT"`

Comment: @DavidJorHpan After I declare the array animals

Comment: I don't want to hard code the string "CaT". I want to pass a parameter through the function that has yet to be passed through (a user input), to evaluate whether it matches the objects in the array or not.

Comment: @Ashton wiat I will edit the answer

Comment: @Ashton try now

Comment: It's still not working with my code. Can you explain what is the .forEach call? And why did you create a new myFunction if it is never used?

Comment: @Ashton .forEach used to navigate through all elements of the animals array one by one. myFunction is call when user click the button seach

Comment: is this formatted only for containers of arrays? Instead of properties of objects?

Comment: @Ashton sorry I didn't get what your are asking ?

Answer (score -3):

```js
function search(animals, name) {
if (animals.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
    var equal = animals.toLocaleLowerCase() === name.toLocaleLowerCase();
    console.log(equal); 
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="search('abc','AbC')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` doesn’t accept any arguments, so how will this be any different?

Comment: i have change my answer, maybe like that?

Comment: No, it doesn’t make a difference.